# Possible typo on "A new hope" hat description

Tags: bug, winter-bash

I had earned the [A New Hope](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/a-new-hope) hat but its description states that you can earn this hat posting a question/answer, or voting on **December 18th**

> Ask, answer, or vote on December 18th

I'm at UTC+1 and today is not Dec 18th...Is this a typo or whatelse?

Comment: I think we should consider to add timezones in the hat descriptions.

Comment: I'm not sure the linked duplicate completely answers the question. It is still more than 12 hours from 18 Dec 00:00 UTC.

Comment: @Martin It does in the dupe chain root: "Unless the requirement mentions a specific timezone, hats that are date-based are often awarded for 14 hours before and 12 hours after the specified date in UTC, to accomodate people everywhere in the world". For example I got it at 12 PM, 17/12 - exactly 12 hours before 18/12

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh right, I didn't even notice the dupe target was closed itself...

Comment: @Martin yeah, it fits because it's a more "exact" dupe than the root - one of the small tweaks of Meta. :)